# mispelled command in UNIX?

Tags: command-line, autocorrection

I don't remember a UNIX command that allowed you to remember how to write correctly a command.

Let's supose that the command that I say is called MISPELL

So running MISPELL will produce the following output:

```
$ MISPELL chlmod
```

Output:

```
chmod
```

Comment: "don't" or "do"?

Comment: what is your OS ? if you use linux, then goto bash shell and type 1 or 2 letters and hit tab key two times. It will show all the executable files matches with your letters

Comment: `[t]csh` will do this for you automatically

Answer (score 5):

For *Ubuntu* distros, install [`command-not-found`](https://launchpad.net/command-not-found/):

```
apt install command-not-found
```

Once installed and enabled, it runs in the current `bash` shell, (more specifically any `bash` shell started *after* installation).  Here's the output if the user types a lone "*chlmod*":

```
No command 'chlmod' found, did you mean:
 Command 'chmod' from package 'coreutils' (main)
chlmod: command not found
```

Comment: +1 Arch Linux info [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Pkgfile#Command_not_found) for bash and zsh.